# Xamarin.Android ViewPager with only ImageViews

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make a ViewPager containing only ImageView.

But it keeps giving me errors on this line.

```
((ViewPager)collection).AddView (i);
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
```

Here is my ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class GalleryAdapter : PagerAdapter
{
    Context context;
    private List<string> mitems;

    public GalleryAdapter (Context c, List<string> items)
    {
        context = c;
        mitems = items;
    }

    public override int Count { get { return mitems.Count; } }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem (View collection, int position)
    {
        ImageView i = new ImageView (context);

        //i.LayoutParameters = new Gallery.LayoutParams (150, 100);
        i.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter);

        Picasso.With (context).Load (mitems [position]).Into (i);
        ((ViewPager)collection).AddView (i);
        return i;
    }

    public override bool IsViewFromObject (View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return view == @object;
    }
}
```

I have no idea where to continue from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the Android documentation, it looks like the first parameter passed to InstantiateItem is just a view which will contain your content, and not necessarily the ViewPager itself. In fact, the version of InstantiateItem which takes a View parameter is deprecated in favour of one which takes a ViewGroup. I'm not sure if the Xamarin wrapper has this method in it, but in either case, try casting to a ViewGroup instead of a ViewPager:

`((ViewGroup)collection).AddView (i);`

You might want to rename the 'collection' variable to 'container' too, just to be clear that you're not adding it directly to the ViewPager, rather to a subview which is owned by the ViewPager.

Comment: Now it doesn't throw any errors, but my view pager seems to be empty

Comment: Try setting your image view's layout parameters to match parent (or wrap content) for width and height, and make sure your images are loading correctly.

Comment: They show now, if i set the PageViewer height, but now my app crashes when i go to the last page, or if I go one back

Comment: If it's an unrelated crash to the one in the question, then you should post a new question with more information about the crash.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem (View collection, int position)
{
    ImageView i = new ImageView (context);

    //i.LayoutParameters = new Gallery.LayoutParams (150, 100);
    i.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter);

    Picasso.With (context).Load (mitems [position]).Into (i);
    var viewPager = collection.JavaCast<ViewPager>();

    viewpager.AddView (i);

    return i;
}
```